# Are there different formats for Mathematica Notebooks and how are MIME types defined in them?

Tags: xfce, mime-types, mathematica

I use Mathematica 12.3 on Xubuntu 20.4. The computer runs with German localization.
I wondered, why one of my notebooks is displayed with the icon usually used for LibreOfficeWriter documents. In the file browser Thunar, this file is shown having the type "Mathematica-Notebook-Datei".
Since I know that Mathematica notebooks are plain ASCII files, I looked at its very beginning with an ASCII-editor. Before the big `Notebook` expression, it looks like this:

```
(*CacheID: 234*)
(* Internal cache information:
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookDataPosition[         0,          0]
NotebookDataLength[     66787,       1565]
NotebookOptionsPosition[     59602,       1429]
NotebookOutlinePosition[     60781,       1460]
CellTagsIndexPosition[     60738,       1457]
WindowFrame->Normal*)

(* Beginning of Notebook Content *)
```

I was able to open this notebook im Mma 12.3, mark all its content, copy it to the clipboard, open a new notebook and paste the clipboard there. In the frontend, the new notebook looked like the old one.

After I stored this new notebook under a different name, the usual Mathematica notebook-icon was assigned to it. I could be happy with that. I wonder how I got to the notebook with the wrong icon.

Thunar displayed the type of the new notebook as "Wolfram Notebook" rather than  "Mathematica-Notebook-Datei". When looking at the beginning of this new notebook, its content before the big "Notebook" expression looks like this in a plain ASCI editor:

```
(* Content-type: application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica *)

(*** Wolfram Notebook File ***)
(* http://www.wolfram.com/nb *)

(* CreatedBy='Mathematica 12.3' *)

(*CacheID: 234*)
(* Internal cache information:
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookDataPosition[       158,          7]
NotebookDataLength[     66111,       1551]
NotebookOptionsPosition[     59760,       1436]
NotebookOutlinePosition[     60263,       1453]
CellTagsIndexPosition[     60220,       1450]
WindowFrame->Normal*)

(* Beginning of Notebook Content *)
```

The difference between the two representations is the absence for the header lines before the line `(*Cache ID: xxx*)` in the former representation (the one with the wrong icon).
I think I did nothing special with the original notebook. But I am curious, what may have caused the maze.

If there is no disadvantage associated to the stripped format version (the one without the  lines before `(*CacheID: xxx*)`), would it be possible to use `xfce4-mime-settings` to assign the right MIME type to it?